# Remove objects from array when deselect table view

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, object

I have a table view which show a list of things with ***id, name, price & quantity*** (got from **itemsArr array**). When I **select one** of the item, I will **append the details** of the thing (*id, name, price, quantity*) **into an array (items array)**. And when I **deselect the item**, **the details (*id, name, price, quantity*)** of the item which has been appended into that array **should be removed**. I have no issues to append the details into an array, but my problem is I *don't know* what is the *best way to remove all the details* of that item from the array. Below is my code:

```
var item = MyList()
var items = [MyList]()
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
        cell?.accessoryType = .checkmark

        if let itemSel = itemsArr?[indexPath.row] {
            delegate?.didSelectItemsListItem(id: itemSel.id, name: itemSel.name, price: itemSel.price)
            // Add item details into array
            item.id = itemSel.id
            item.name = itemSel.name
            item.price = itemSel.price
            item.quantity = 1
            self.items.append(item)
            print("Added items: ", self.items)
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
        cell?.accessoryType = .none
        // Remove item details from array
        if let itemdeSel = itemsArr?[indexPath.row] {
            delegate?.didDeselectItemsListItem(id: itemdeSel.id, name: itemdeSel.name, price: itemdeSel.price)
            if let index = itemsArr?.index(where: { $0.id == itemdeSel.id }) {
                // removing item
                self.items.remove(at: index)
                print("Items after removed: ", self.items)
            }
        }
    }
```

noted that the **quantity for all items is 1**. I want to try using filter method but I'm afraid that all quantity of other items will also be removed since the quantity is the same. Below is the example of items array (which the items has been appended into it:

```
 [(id: 4, name: "book", price: "3.00", quantity: 1), (id: 2, name: "pen", price: "1.00", quantity: 1)]
```

**UPDATE:**
I can actually just use the filter method. I didn't know filter method can remove the whole details of that item. Below is my final deSelect code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    cell?.accessoryType = .none
    // Remove item details from array
    if let itemdeSel = itemsArr?[indexPath.row] {
        delegate?.didDeselectItemsListItem(id: itemdeSel.id, name: itemdeSel.name, price: itemdeSel.price)
        let filteredArray = self.items.filter { $0.id != itemdeSel.id }
        self.items.removeAll()
        self.items = filteredArray
        print("Items after removed: ", self.items)
    }
}
```

Comment: If the `id` values are unique, then why would it remove everything else?

Comment: What is this `item` variable in your `didSelectRowAt `? Is it an instance variable?

Comment: @SShahid, I'm sorry I don't understand your question. But yes, the id value is unique. Are you referring about the filter method?

Comment: @Tj3n, var item = MyList(), MyList is a model. and the items array is from var items = [MyList]()

Comment: @Lynn, in your didDeselectRowAt function, you are removing the object. Why do you think that the filter method would not work, if you are deleting them by checking for their `id`? :)

Comment: @SShahid, I thought the filter method only delete the id only, not deleting the whole details. I'm sorry I'm quite new to swift and not familiar with this thing yet. Can you suggest me the way using the filter method according to my problem? (which can delete the whole details of that item by only checking the id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an array, `itemsArr`, and you know the id of the item that you want to remove, you can simple use,

```
let filteredArray = itemsArr.filter { $0.id != idToDelete }
```